# BRST Quantization of the Bosonic String: Nilpotence of BRST transformation (Polchinski)

Tags: string-theory, variational-calculus, grassmann-numbers, brst, ghosts

Currently I am studying string theory and I encountered a bunch of interrelated problems in the context of BRST quantization which I can't solve for myself although I tried hard for some days.

My question concerns the BRST transformation of the bosonic string in eq. (4.3.1) of Polchinski's book. In the paragraph following these transformations, Polchinski says that *"the reader can check nilpotence up to the equations of motion"*. I tried but wasn't able to complete the proof - here my calculations:

$$\begin{align}
\delta_\mathrm{B}\delta_\mathrm{B}'X^\mu&=\delta_\mathrm{B}\left[\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left(c\partial X^\mu+\bar{c}\bar{\partial}X^\mu\right)\right]\\[2pt]
&=\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left[(\delta_\mathrm{B}c)\partial X^\mu+c(\delta_\mathrm{B}\partial X^\mu)+(\delta_\mathrm{B}\bar{c})\partial X^\mu+\bar{c}(\delta_\mathrm{B}\bar{\partial} X^\mu)\right]\\[2pt]
&=\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left[(\mathrm{i}\varepsilon c\partial c)\partial X^\mu+c(\mathrm{i}\varepsilon(c\partial\partial X^\mu+\bar{c}\underbrace{\bar{\partial}\partial X^\mu}_{=0}))+(\mathrm{i}\varepsilon\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{c})\bar{\partial}X^\mu+\bar{c}(\mathrm{i}\varepsilon(c\underbrace{\partial\bar{\partial}X^\mu}_{=0}+\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}X^\mu))\right]\\[2pt]
&=-\varepsilon'\left[\varepsilon c\partial c\partial X^\mu+c\varepsilon c\partial\partial X^\mu+\varepsilon\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{c}\bar{\partial}X^\mu+\bar{c}\varepsilon\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}X^\mu\right]\\[2pt]
&=-\varepsilon'\varepsilon \left[c\partial c\partial X^\mu-\underbrace{c c}_{=0}\partial\partial X^\mu+\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{c}\bar{\partial}X^\mu-\underbrace{\bar{c}\bar{c}}_{=0}\bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}X^\mu\right]\\[2pt]
&=-\varepsilon'\varepsilon \left[c\partial c\partial X^\mu+\bar{c}\bar{\partial}\bar{c}\bar{\partial}X^\mu\right]\\[2pt]
&=?
\end{align}$$

Here I used the equation of motion for the field $X^\mu$ and exploited $c^2=0=\bar{c}^2$. **At this point, however, I do not see why the remaining terms should vanish.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The infinitesimal BRST transformation $$\delta_{\mathrm{B}}\left(F[X,c,\ldots]\right)~:=~F[X+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}X,c+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}c,\ldots]-F[X,c,\ldots]\tag{A}$$ acts "under" the spacetime derivatives marked in red, i.e. OP's second line should read
$$\begin{align}
\delta_{\mathrm{B}}\delta_\mathrm{B}'X^\mu
&\stackrel{(4.3.1a)}=\delta_\mathrm{B}\left[\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left(c\color{red}{\partial} X^\mu+\bar{c}\color{red}{\bar{\partial}}X^\mu\right)\right]\\[2pt]
&~~~\stackrel{(A)}=~~~\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left[(c+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}c)\color{red}{\partial} (X^\mu+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}X^\mu)+(\bar{c}+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}\bar{c})\color{red}{\bar{\partial}}(X^\mu+\delta_{\mathrm{B}}X^\mu)-c\color{red}{\partial} X^\mu-\bar{c}\color{red}{\bar{\partial}}X^\mu\right]\\[2pt]
&~~~=~~~\mathrm{i}\varepsilon'\left[(\delta_\mathrm{B}c)\color{red}{\partial} X^\mu +c\color{red}{\partial}(\delta_\mathrm{B}X^\mu) +(\delta_\mathrm{B}\bar{c})\color{red}{\bar{\partial}} X^\mu +\bar{c}\color{red}{\bar{\partial}}(\delta_\mathrm{B}X^\mu)\right]\\[2pt]
&~~~=~~~\ldots\tag{B}
\end{align}$$

Comment: 1. What is the explanation that $\delta_\mathrm{B}$ acts under the spacetime derivatives? Considering the general BRST transformation (4.2.6a), the field $\phi_i$ can be $\textbf{any}$ non-ghost field. 2. In (4.2.22a) however, this very general transformation behaviour collapses to the transformation of $X^\mu$ and $e$ (without any derivatives!). Why is this the case?

Comment: 1. I updated the answer.  2. There is a derivative wrt. $\tau$ in eqs. (4.2.22a) & (4.2.22a) if you look in Polchinski's book. It's denoted with a dot.